# burpsuite intruder and hashed passwords

Tags: javascript, html

In order to learn how to use Burpsuite, I am trying to use it to hack into the management gui on an IP camera of mine. Access credentials are currently admin/admin.  From Burpsuite's proxy I select the following POST command for an intruder attack:

```html
POST /login/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.XXX.XXX.173
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://10.XXX.XXX.173/
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 29
DNT: 1
Connection: close
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

username=admin&password=admin
```

When I run a sniper attack using a list of passwords, including admin, all the tries come back with the exact same 200 success response/message. Investigating further, I see that after each attack and response message, there is a subsequent GET message from the browser that looks like this:

```html
GET /login/?_=1551456400210&_username=admin&_login=true&_signature=§de6af126fa27f887c20ca2de02411aa913815d9b§ HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.XXX.XXX.173
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://10.XXX.XXX.173/
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
DNT: 1
Connection: close
```

And this generates a success response in the case of admin/admin and a failure response in other cases.  So, it appears the camera is hashing the password and passing on the hash in the "signature" element of the GET command.  If I use the GET command for the sniper attack and include the hashed value in the password list, the attack sees the hash of "admin" as being successful.

At this point, it appears that I need a two-part attack.  Part one gets the hashes of the password list from the gui and part two tells me when a hash/password works to unlock the gui.  Am I right?  How do I do this in Burpsuite?

Comment: FWIW, I entered de6af126fa27f887c20ca2de02411aa913815d9b into the hash cracker at https://crackstation.net/ and it returned type unknown and result not found.  Does not bode well for rainbow tables.